# Hyperlink in CellRendererText Markup

Tags: hyperlink, pygtk

I want to display a hyperlink in a pygtk table:

```
cr=gtk.CellRendererText()
column=gtk.TreeViewColumn(name)
column.add_attribute(cr, "markup", 0)

my_liststore=['<a href="http://google.com/">google</a>', ...]
```

Hyperlink "a" seems not supported by the markup. I get this warning:

```
GtkWarning: Failed to set text from markup due to error parsing markup: Unknown tag 'a' on line 1
```

How can I display a hyperlink in a pygtk table? And of course it should open the browser if you click on it ...

**Update**

Several month after asking this question: Here is my personal advice: don't use gtk. It is a dead horse. I don't know if Qt is better. The way to go is web technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the lines which I use now. The cell gets rendered with blue color and underlined. The double click event calls a callback with uses the webbrowser module.

```
table = gtk.TreeView(list_store)

cr = gtk.CellRendererText()

# allow pango markup
column.add_attribute(cr, "markup", i) 

# connect double click handler:
self.timeline.connect('row-activated', self.on_treeview_click)

# content in the data rows:
u'<span foreground="blue" underline="single">%s</span>' % (
                    glib.markup_escape_text(name))
```

Callback:

```
    def on_treeview_click(self, treeview, path, view_column):
        model=treeview.get_model()
        action_id=model[path][0]
        url='....' # build your url
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open(url)
```